# Trying to run newaliases: newaliases: fatal: /etc/: file has 85 hard links

Tags: ubuntu, alias, postfix-mta, hardlink

I just updated my `/etc/aliases` file like so:

```
postmaster: root
mailer-daemon: postmaster
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
root: myusername
```

However now I am getting an error while running newaliases:

```
newaliases: fatal: /etc/: file has 85 hard links
```

And now postfix will not start:

```
# postfix start
postfix: fatal: /etc/: file has 85 hard links
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. Do not do what I did and blindly copy/paste things from tutorials. Make sure you properly read up on the configuration options and know what they mean.

http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#myorigin

This was part of my /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

```
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
myorigin = /etc/
```

I had forgotten to complete the myorigin line or it had gotten messed up somewhere along the way. What I meant to put was this:

```
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
myorigin = </etc/mailname
```

The < tells postfix to read that file. Now `newaliases` and all of the `postfix` commands work perfectly.